# Can't clear all items (elements) in an ObservableList

Tags: javafx, removeall, observablelist

I've a couple of copied elements in an observablelist which I use for copy/paste operations in a TableView. The name of the table is **cpTable** (**c**opy and **p**aste **T**able) for storing copied elements and to paste elements that are stored in the table. After each paste operation I want to clear the contents of cpTable before I copy other selected items with Ctrl+C.
But I always get the error:

> JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Not supported.
>   at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.remove(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:246)

Here is my pseudocode:

```
if (cpTable !=null) {
    //first, get all copied items for removing all elements 
    ObservableList<String> copiedItems = cpTable.getItems();                                 
    int size = copiedItems.size();

    // remove all elements 
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
        copiedItems.remove(i);
    }
    cpTable.setItems(copiedItems); //clear cpTable by setting an empty list
}
```

This is a method that copies the contents of selected items and puts it in a cpTable

```
public TableView<String> copySelectionToClipboard(TableView<String> table) {            
    ObservableList<String> data =     table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();             
    TableView<String> tmp = new TableView<>();
    tmp.setItems(data);
    return tmp;
```

}

When Ctrl+C is pressed the following line puts all copied items in a cpTable:

```
cpTable = copySelectionToClipboard( (TableView<String>) keyEvent.getSource());
```

As mentioned I want to clear all cpTable contents immediately after pasting
the items in a table.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just clear your Observable List. It looks like you should use `copiedItems.clear();`
That should clear your table.

Answer (score 3):

As James_D already mentioned, you haven't cleared exactly what's the point.

If you want to delete selected items from a table, you need to delete them from the table item list itself and not from the selection model.

A possible solution looks like this:

```
TableView<String> table = new TableView<>();
ObservableList<String> tableItems = table.getItems();

// needs multirowselection is set to true
ObservableList<String> readOnlyItems = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems(); 

// removes all selected elements for the table
readOnlyItems.stream().forEach((item) -> {
    tableItems.remove(item);
});

// clear the selection
table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

### Update

This method get's an TableView, calls it's selection model to get all selected items. And then you add the data to a new TableView. And there is the problem! It's an unmodifiable read only list that you attached to your new table. First make it modifiable, like in the code below:

```
public TableView<String> copySelectionToClipboard(TableView<String> table) {            
    ObservableList<String> readOnlyData = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    ObservableList<String> writableData = FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(readOnlyData);
    TableView<String> tmp = new TableView<>();
    tmp.setItems(writableData);
    return tmp;
```

The next problem is in your call to this method. You call it with a `TableView<CsvData>` and with a `TableView<String>` as your method needs. If CsvData is a subtype of String, than you have to change your method signature to `TableView<? extends String>`

Comment: ok, I edited my question. Please have a look at my pseudocode, too.

Comment: @Ramses How do you create the table items? Or the list of table items? Can you show your code. Maybe you get a Collection from FXCollections that is not initialized by a backed Collection or is read only.

Comment: my code is too large and too complex to put it here. Theefore, I've added the most important methods, **copySelectionToClipboard** and a line for cpTable declaration

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean

```
table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()
```

(since the selection model has no `getItems()` method), according to the [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.TableViewSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--), this returns a **read-only** list. Thus attempting to modify the list will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

To clear the selection, do

```
table.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
```

(And similarly, if you want to manipulate the selection in any other way, you use methods on the selection model, rather than on the list.)

Comment: ok, I edited my question. Please have a look at my pseudocode again. I don't want to clear the table selection. Instead, I want to clear all items in a list.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to clear all the items from your `tableView` and want just an empty `tableView`. You can use this:

```
myTableView.getItems().clear();
```

This basically gets all the items from your table view which is nothing but just the observable list now it performs clear operations to remove all the items in `tableView`.